# How to count number of words that start with a string

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a code that counts prefix's,suffix's, and roots.
All I need to know is how to count the numbers of words that start or end with a certain string such as 'co'.

this is what I have so far.

```
SWL=open('mediumWordList.txt').readlines()
  for x in SWL:
      x.lower
      if x.startswith('co'):
          a=x.count(x)
while a==True:
    a=+1
    print a
```

all I get from this is an infinite loop of ones.

Comment: Well...you have `while True` loop which never turns to `False` hence `infinite`

Comment: General code notes: `x.lower` by itself is a no-op; it looks up the `str.lower` method, then does nothing with it. You'd want `x = x.lower()` (the parens actually call `lower`, and you must assign back to `x` because `x.lower()` returns a new string, it doesn't mutate the `str` in place (Python's `str` is immutable, nothing changes it in place). Also, `a=+1` is syntactically legal, but it means `a = (+1)` (equivalent to `a = 1`); you probably meant `a += 1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all as a more pythonic way for dealing with files you can use `with` statement to open the file which close the file automatically at the end of the block.

Also you don't need to use `readlines` method to load all the line in memory you can simply loop over the file object.

And about the counting the words you need to split your lines to words then use `str.stratswith` and `str.endswith` to count the words based on your conditions.

So you can use a generator expression within `sum` function to count the number of your words :

```
with open('mediumWordList.txt') as f:
   sum(1 for line in f for word in line.split() if word.startswith('co'))
```

Note that we need to split the line to access the words, if you don't split the lines you'll loop over the all characters of the line.

As suggested in comments as a more pythonic way you can use following approach :

```
with open('mediumWordList.txt') as f:
   sum(word.startswith('co') for line in f for word in line.split())
```

Comment: Alternative approach is to avoid filtering in the generator expression; `True` is 1, and `False` is 0 numerically, so you can do: `sum(word.startswith('co') for line in f for word in line.split())` using the result of the `startswith` check directly. Neither one is innately superior, just mentioning it for completeness.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Indeed, I forgot that, thanks for improvement!

Comment: This worked great! I still have the issue of stripping and lowering the list. any idea how I could do that? much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Counter class from collections. For example, to count 'Foo' in Bar.txt:

```
    from collections import Counter
    with open('Bar.txt') as barF:
      words = [word for line in barF.readlines() for word in line.split()]
    c = Counter(words)
    print c['Foo']
```

Comment: how do I modify that code to count 'co' from 'mediumWordList.txt'

Comment: from collections import Counter
            with open('mediumWordList.txt') as barF:
              words = [word for line in barF.readlines() for word in line.split()]
            c = Counter(words)
            NumberOfCOWords =  c['co']